# Format and Extract JSON

Tags: javascript, json, format, extract

I would like to extract JSON data **OUTPUT** in the following format.
JSON:

```
{
   "person":{
      "givenName":"alpha",
      "surname":"bravo",
      "Info":{
         "status":"active",
         "userid":"userid_cn",
         "roles":[
            "faculty.role1",
            "faculty.role2"
         ],
         "studynum":"2122",
         "email":"alpha.bravo@email.com"
      }
   }
}
```

---

However, what I have currently is

```
function createInfo(status, userid,studynum,email) {
    var objectString = "{\"status\": \"active\",\"userid\": \"" + userid + "\",\"roles\": [\"faculty.role1\",\"faculty.role2\"],\"studynum\":\"" + 
    studynum + "\",\"email\": \""+ email + "\"}";
    var orgInfoJSon = JSON.parse(objectString);
    return orgInfoJSon;
}

//Create Student JSON object

function CreateStudent(givenName, surname) {
    var objectString = "{\"givenName\": \"" + givenName + "\",\"surname\": \"" + surname + "\"}";
    var StudentJSON = JSON.parse(objectString);
    return StudentJSON;
}

//Create Full JSON

function CreateFacultyUpdateJSON(givenName, surname,status, userid,studynum,email) {
    var returnJSON = CreateStudent(givenName, surname);
    returnJSON["Info"] = createInfo(status, userid,studynum,email);
    return returnJSON;
}
```

It generates  part of the expected outcome, but I am stuck on how to include the first  key part, the "person".  Any clues/ideas on how to include the "person", to enable extracting the whole data, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you generating JSON by mashing strings together in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually build a JSON string that you'll parse immediatly after. You'd rather create directly a JS Object.

If you want to add the `Info` directly in the object student, you can pass it as parameter in the function that build the Student :

```js
function createInfo(status, userid, studynum, email) {
    const obj = {
        status: status,
        userid : userid,
        roles: [ "faculty.role1", "faculty.role2" ],
        studynum: studynum,
        email: email
    };
    return obj;
}

// Add the info object --------------------v--v
function CreateStudent(givenName, surname, info) {
    const obj = {
        person: {
            givenName: givenName,
            surname: surname,
            Info: info
        }
    };

    return obj;
}

const  info = createInfo("active", "userid_cn", "2122", "alpha.bravo@email.com");

const student = CreateStudent("alpha", "bravo", info)

console.log(student);
```

---

Note that a *JSON Object* doesn't exist. A *JSON string* Does

Comment: @   Cid    thanks for the suggestion.  I need the output in one main external block, not 2 different blocks.  So how to merge them, to enable getting output as in one block, as indicated in the original post.  Thanks for your support.

Comment: @ Cid,   Thanks for the improvement.  However, the content of the inner array ain't coming out, as it appears showing roles: [Array],  , instead of  roles:["faculty.role1", "faculty.role2"].     Thanks for your support

Comment: @ Cid,   Thanks for your support.